# How to check if a function call having too many or too few arguments in a Haskell project

Tags: function, haskell, error-handling

I am working on the Haskell project,
For the error checking, I need to take care of any function call having too many or too few arguments, but I currently have no idea for it.Hoping to get same hints to start.

Comment: Haskell has a static type system, this means that if you call the function with too few or too many parameters, then it will raise a compiler error. Furthermore note that strictly speaking in Haskell every function has *exactly one* parameter.

Comment: Is that possible to catch that compiler error and than do some other thing?Just do not let the program terminate.

Comment: but why? It is non-sensical to perform a function call on a `Int` for example, that does not make any sense. It means someone has wrote something non-sensical. Haskell aims to provide a type system that normally tries to elimiate most "technical" errors in the code. So besides for example an algorithmic/conceptual error, it aims to make sure you don't get a lot of errors in the first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless one uses some form of advanced *ad hoc polymorphism* like the [**`printf :: PrintfType r => String -> r`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) does, the compiler will notice.

Indeed, if you have a function like:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add = (+)
```

if you call it with three parameters, like `add 2 4 5`, then this will raise an error. This will happen, since `add 2 4 5`, or more canonical `((add 2) 4) 5`, will try to eventually make a call to an item that is an `Int`. Indeed `add 2` has type `add 2 :: Int -> Int`, and thus `(add 2) 4` has type `(add 2) 4 :: Int`, so since that is not function, the compiler will raise an error:

```
Prelude> add 2 4 5
<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Int’
    • The function ‘add’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘Int -> Int -> Int’ has only two
      In the expression: add 2 4 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = add 2 4 5
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:5:1)
```

It thus says it expected a type (`Integer -> t`, although the `Integer` here is due to type defaulting), but got an `Int` instead. So that is not possible.

Calling a function with "too few" parameters is not really possible, since if you call it with too few, you simply generate a function that expects to take the next parameter. This is the idea behind [*currying* [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying). Indeed, if the type of `add 2` is:

```
Prelude> :t add 2
add 2 :: Int -> Int
```

It is a function that expects the following parameter. It is possible that this will clash with another function that expects an `Int`, but then you will get a similar exception except that the expected will be a non-function (`Int`) for example, and the actual type is a function, so something like:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘Integer -> t’
```

Haskell's type system will thus error in case you call a function with too much arguments, or when you use the result of a function with too few arguments.

Note that strictly speaking in Haskell every function only takes *one* parameter. If you do not provide one, then the outcome is still a function, if you provide one, you make a function call, but that function can produce another function thus expects the next parameter.

The reason that `printf` can take one, two, or more parameters, is because of the instances of the [**`PrintfType`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#t:PrintfType). This can be an `IO a` that will thus then print the result of the formatted string, or a function `(PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => a -> r` that thus will take a parameter of the `PrintfArg` type, and return another `PrintfType` type. It can thus each time specialize in an extra function if another function is necessary. But this thus emulates a *variadic* function, where you can pass an arbitrary number of parameters.